# Nodejs Mongodb Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using NodeJs and MongoDB (no mongoose) and I want:

- To check if a collection exist.
- Create collection if not.
- Wait for creation process to end.
- Do stuff on collection.

```
  mongoClient.connect(serverUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, client) {
        if (err) { throw err};
        var db = client.db(useDB);

        db.collection(data.to).countDocuments({}, function (err, names) {
            if (names == 0) {
            db.collection(data.to).insertOne(defaultCollec);
            return console.log('Created:'+data.to)
            }
            if (err) console.log(err)
        }).then(function (db) { 
            //Do stuff after creation
            return console.log('After Creation')
          });
```

Error:

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

I'm having quite a pain with chaining and arrows function...

Comment: I believe those methods either take callbacks *or* return promises - pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`countDocuments` has 4 possible signatures in `nodejs`:

```
countDocuments(callback: MongoCallback<number>): void;
countDocuments(query: FilterQuery<TSchema>, callback: MongoCallback<number>): void;
countDocuments(query?: FilterQuery<TSchema>, options?: MongoCountPreferences): Promise<number>;
countDocuments(query: FilterQuery<TSchema>, options: MongoCountPreferences, callback: MongoCallback<number>): void;
```

You are trying to use 2 of the signatures simultaneously, you're using the callback signature that returns nothing, and then you're trying to use the `then` method ( a promise function ) on that null value.

If you for some reason you prefer on using callback instead of promise then you need to wrap it with a `Promise` to preserve the logic, like so:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection(data.to).countDocuments({}, function (err, names) {
        if (names == 0) {
            db.collection(data.to).insertOne(defaultCollec);
            return console.log('Created:'+data.to)
        }
        if (err) console.log(err);
        resolve(console.log('After Creation'))
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

mongodb has that callback function in

mongoClient.connect(serverUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, **function (err, client) {}**

the highlighted text is the cb(){} or try to remove that and try the below,

```
mongoClient.connect(serverUrl, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
            .then()
            .catch()
```